# Vertical scroll inside a div?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a mobile site with masthead and burger menu at the top.
The HTML is like below:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="cssmenu">...</div> // this is the collapsed burger menu with masthead
   <div id="wrap">
      <div id="title">...</div> // page title
      <div id="content">...</div> // paragraph
   </div>
</div>
```

The #cssmenu has fixed position. So when users scroll down the page, the title and content actually scroll **underneath** the masthead and cause some issues for on-page anchors. Is there a way to allow the #wrap only vertically scroll within its own div?

Comment: overflow-y: 'scroll'

Answer (score 2):

You could fix your #wrap container as well.

```css
#cssmenu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.1);
}
#wrap {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
#title,
#content {
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
   <div id="cssmenu">menu</div>
   <div id="wrap">
      <div id="title">top of title</div>
      <div id="content">top of content</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/e2qb9hu7/

---

You could also use fixed height based on viewport height.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
#cssmenu {
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.1);
}
#wrap {
  height: 90vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
#title,
#content {
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
   <div id="cssmenu">menu</div>
   <div id="wrap">
      <div id="title">top of title</div>
      <div id="content">top of content</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/4rd1f9vt/